# How can i specify start & end position in CATransition?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, catransition

I want to use CATransition animation in my apps but I don't know that how can i specify start & end position of CATransition animation.I used UITabelview to display data & select a row animation is display with details but not proper animation is display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the transformations in `NSValue` instances when you set them on your `CABasicAnimation`instance. For example like this:

```
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3d:fromTransform];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3d:toTransform];
```